# Inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got ANYDATA

Tags: sql, oracle

I am retrieving table values by comparing against one of the elements in clob column of the table.
However, my query is returning following error:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got ANYDATA
>
> 932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

```
select * 
from DEMOTBL MDT 
where EXTRACTVALUE(XMLPARSE(CONTENT MDT.MKT_MSG_DATA),'/MKT_MSG_DATA/sendDetail/hrg/tt/text()') = 'BIADTEST';
```

what exactly the issue is here?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the CLOB value that gives that error - or at least the relevant nodes if it's large - and your Oracle version. Are you sure your column is actually a CLOB, not XMLType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query [seems to work](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a6b51f8cf2601515e012cd0b5019a235) with CLOB values; but get's that error if the data is actually [already an XMLType](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c7e5f96d72f4a6359e6b4d7af2c222bd) rather than a CLOB.

If that is the case then you can fix it just by removing the XMLParse call:

```
select * from DEMOTBL MDT
where EXTRACTVALUE(MDT.MKT_MSG_DATA,'/MKT_MSG_DATA/sendDetail/hrg/tt/text()') = 'BIADTEST';
```

But `extractvalue` is deprecated, so it would be better to XMLQuery:

```
select * from DEMOTBL MDT
where XMLQuery('/MKT_MSG_DATA/sendDetail/hrg/tt/text()'
  passing MDT.MKT_MSG_DATA
  returning content).getstringval() = 'BIADTEST';
```

or XMLExists:

```
select * from DEMOTBL MDT
where XMLExists('/MKT_MSG_DATA/sendDetail/hrg/tt[text()="BIADTEST"]'
  passing MDT.MKT_MSG_DATA);
```

[db<>fiddle with XMLType data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d2b26382f32bb338a5272b52f2d0ce86); and [with CLOB data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b750d4286f17a164e0fc73c08688e58a) converted to XMLType using either that type's constructor or XMLParse.

Comment: One clarification...does cloud support XMLExists or XMLQuery ?

Comment: These are standard functions, so I don't see why it wouldn't. If you're having an issue then you'll need to ask a new question giving details of your environment (Oracle version/release, OS etc.), the code you're running, and any error you get.